# Why can't I get time zone back from Oracle by calling a stored procedure from Java?

Tags: java, oracle, date-format

I have a stored procedure to get data time back with time zone, like:

```
select 
    to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020-DEC-15 05:10','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI AM TZD') 
from dual;
```

When I execute this stored procedure directly from SQL Developer, the result is:

```
2020-12-15 05:10 AM EST
```

But if I call this stored procedure from Java code, it returns

```
2020-12-15 05:10 AM
```

The time zone is not retrieved.

What's the reason that cause the difference? How can I get time zone back from Java?

Comment: How are you retrieving the SP value (which Java class) ? Can you post some relevant Java code.

Comment: Then please show a [mcve] java code.  thanks

Comment: When you don’t show us how you retrieve the timestamp into Java, we have no chance of telling.